# react router Link doesn't cause rerender when visited on the same path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I'm using react router v4, had some issue reloading the page (not window.location.reload). I better give a real use case to explain the issue, we use a social network app as the example:

1. user A commented a post by user B, a notification appear in user B page.
2. user B clicked on the notification, we do `this.props.history.push('/job/' + id')`, it worked, hence user B went to `job/123` page.
3. user A commented again, new notification appear in user B page, while user B still remain on the `job/123` page, he clicked on the notification link and triggered `this.props.history.push('/job' + id')`. But he won't see the page rerender, he DID NOT see the latest comment because the page does nothing.

Comment: that's a good explanation, but it would be best to see your code that is relevant to this problem, otherwise it would be very hard to help you.

Comment: @AndrewLohr it's hard for me to replicate as I'm using websocket, real time notification been pushed from user A to user B that's why there's a possibility that user B click the new notification on the same path.

Comment: I think your problem is about pushing too same route and your component doesn't update after pushing. `postId` isn't different in `/notification` pages? `postId` is 123 in both pages?

Comment: @soroushchehresa I think using `/notification/postId` will confused people, I changed it to job, each job detail has comment, the notification is just to tell the user there's a new notification in a specified job page.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a common scenario in many cases. It can be tackled using many different approaches. Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839510/forcing-a-react-router-link-to-load-a-page-even-if-were-already-on-that-page). There are some good answers and findings. Personally [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837248/1453339) made more sense to me.

`location.key` changes every single time whenever user tries to navigate between pages, even within the same `route`. To test this place below block of code in you `/jod/:id` component:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.key !== this.props.location.key) {
      console.log("... prevProps.key", prevProps.location.key)
      console.log("... this.props.key", this.props.location.key)
    }
  }
```

I had this exact same situation. Updated state in `componentDidUpdate`. After that worked as expected. Clicking on items within the same route updates state and displays correct info.

I assume (as not sure how you're passing/updating comments in `/job/:id`) if you set something like this in your `/job/:id` component should work:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.key !== this.props.location.key) {

      this.setState({
        comments: (((this.props || {}).location || {}).comments || {})
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are describing 2 different kinds of state changes.

In the first scenario, when user B is *not* at the `/job/:id` page and he clicks a link you get a URL change, which triggers a state change in the router, and propagates that change through to your component so you can see the comment.

In the second scenario, when user B is *already at* the `/job/:id` page and a new comment comes through, the URL doesn't need to change, so clicking on a link won't change the URL and won't trigger a state change in the router, so you won't see the new content.

I would probably try something like this (pseudo code because I don't know how you're getting new comments or subscribing via the websocket):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The home page</h1>

        {/* This is the link that the user sees when someone makes a new comment */}
        <Link to="/job/123">See the new comment!</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Job extends React.Component {
  state = { comments: [] };

  fetchComments() {
    // Fetch the comments for this job from the server,
    // using the id from the URL.
    fetchTheComments(this.props.params.id, comments => {
      this.setState({ comments });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch the comments once when we first mount.
    this.fetchComments();

    // Setup a listener (websocket) to listen for more comments. When
    // we get a notification, re-fetch the comments.
    listenForNotifications(() => {
      this.fetchComments();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Job {this.props.params.id}</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.comments.map(comment => (
            <li key={comment.id}>{comment.text}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/job/:id" component={Job} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Now the page will get updated in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

this solved the problem for me :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>  
 <Switch>

     <Redirect from="/x_walls/:user_Id" to='/walls/:user_Id'/>
     <Route path="/walls/:user_Id" exact render={(props) => <Wall {...props}/> }/>           

  </Switch>

</Router>
```

and when you want to call "walls" you just call "x_walls" instead