# React-Router <Link> to load a page, even if we're already on that page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react router in my website. I have homepage and contact.

When I am on homepage and I click on the homepage again. How can I reload the page like Facebook

issue here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982

Comment: like Facebook??

Comment: If you are on the home page (facebook) and you click on the home navigation. It still reloads the page

Comment: Create a regular link, using a regular `<a href="/">Home</a>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the issue, I can realize that you may use force update:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  }
```

Comment: this.props.location !== prevProps.location is always trueee

Comment: And it was called serveral time after componentDidMount

Comment: Only detect specific change what you need and then update. I have given you just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an event handler on the 'home' Link, that will fetch the data you want to be updated.

```
      class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick () {
    // code that fetches Home Page data
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Link to='your/path' onClick={this.handleClick}>Home</Link>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nav and Home is two different components so it does not work like that

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to update on your home page and where is it stored?

Comment: I use redux and action. It is a little bit weird if we put that login in Nav

Comment: If your simply trying to dispatch an action to revert or update your home component. Give my suggestion a try, it should work. If not maybe have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839510/forcing-a-react-router-link-to-load-a-page-even-if-were-already-on-that-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This might be a common problem and I was looking for a decent solution to have in my toolbet for next time. **React-Router** provides some mechanisms to know when an user tries to visit any page even the one they are already.

Reading the `location.key` hash, it's the perfect approach as it changes every-time the user try to navigate between any page.

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.key !== this.props.location.key) {
        this.setState({
            isFormSubmitted: false,
        })
    }
}
```

Reference: [*A location object is never mutated so you can use it in the lifecycle hooks to determine when navigation happens*](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/location.md)