# how to re render component on Link click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

As Danilo pointed out in the comments this is a duplicate of [Forcing a React-Router <Link> to load a page, even if we're already on that page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839510/forcing-a-react-router-link-to-load-a-page-even-if-were-already-on-that-page)

---

I have a route that has a simple navbar and content below it.

The `<Link>` from react-router-dom does nothing when clicked on the same page's url.

```js
<Route path="/samePage" component={Component} />
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function SomeNavBar(){
   return (
      <Link to="/samePage">Refresh</Link>
   );
}

function Component(){
    // some state
    let [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      // fetch data from API here
    });

    return (
    <>
       <SomeNavBar />
       {/* Displaying the state*/}
    </>);
}
```

I'd like to refresh the state on the click of the `Link` in the NavBar. So one option is to use `<a href>` instead of `<Link to="" />` because it will reload the page and does what's desired.

But reloading is bad as we're using React so how can I re-render the route on click?

Comment: Are you basically trying to create a button that refetches data from your API?

Comment: That can be done but I'd like to change the behavior of the `Link` so that when I click on it from a different route I go to the route which the Link points to, whereas if I'm on the same page I need it to act as a button which re-renders the current route's component. I thought there might be an inbuilt way to do this without handling this myself.

Comment: Refresh the state on the click of the Link -> `onClick={() => setData([])}` ?

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839510/forcing-a-react-router-link-to-load-a-page-even-if-were-already-on-that-page

Comment: @DaniloGacevic thanks for finding that question. I wasn't able to get it on google so I had to ask this. This can be closed as a Duplicate.