# Fetch user info when redirected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my application i want to fetch some user information when i redirect the user to the main page after the login. For this, i use useEffect with an empty array as dependecy so i only get the data when the components first loads. But, for some reason, i only get the data when i reload the main page, not when i get redirected.

**login function**

```
export const login = ({ email, password, history }) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === 200) {
        dispatch(setUser({
          fullname: data.fullname,
          email: data.email
        }));
        localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.user);
        history.push("/");
      } else {
        dispatch(
          setNotification({
            variant: "error",
            message: data.message,
          })
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };
};
```

**Here is the code i used on the frontend to get the user info**

```
export const fetchUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/userInfo", {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem('userToken'),
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch(
        setUser({
          id: data.id,
          fullname: data.fullname,
          email: data.email,
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };
```

**Backend code where i get the token as header and verify it to get the user information**

```
module.exports.getCurrentUser = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
  try {
    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, "123");
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: verifyToken.email });
    return res.json({
      id: user._id,
      fullname: user.fullname,
      email: user.email
    })
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

**I´m calling the useEffect inside my app.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const isAuth = isLoggedIn();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchUser());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuth) {
      return;
    }
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }
      if (cart.changed) {
        dispatch(sendCartData(cart));
      }
  }, [cart]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/componentes" exact>
          <Components />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" exact>
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cadastro" exact>
          <Register />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/produto/:nomeProduto" exact>
          <SingleProduct />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/componente/suspensao" exact>
          <Suspension />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/componente/quadro" exact>
          <Frame />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/marca/:brand" exact>
          <Brands />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/carrinho" exact>
          <Cart />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/equipamentos" exact>
          <Equipments />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/acessorios" exact>
          <Accessories />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/casual" exact>
          <Casual />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `<Router/>` component wrapping that `<Switch/>` in a higher level component than what is shown? Is this redirect only occurring within same react app instance or is it a whole new page load?

Comment: I have a <BrowserRouter /> component  wrapping the app component. What do you mean by only occurring within same react app instance?

Comment: Just mean are you only changing to a new `<Route/>` or is there a complete page reload involved. Hard to troubleshoot without more debugging details

Comment: I´m just changing to a new route

Comment: So does second request get made to `userInfo` path in dev tools network and if so is it  200 status? Not sure what is and what isn't working here yet

Comment: The request i made to userInfo only shows when i refresh the page, and its status code is 200

Comment: So it never even gets made after redirect? If not then what does work when that component gets mounted?

Comment: Ok so go into that component and see what is working. See if useEffect gets entered... see if ` dispatch(fetchUser());` gets called etc. This is not easy to help on without having a full working version

Comment: useEffect is called when i redirect, but fetchUser() is not

Comment: Well that seems strange and would be a place to start digging into

Comment: Indeed. I'll keep working on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<App/>` component is not being mounted when the route changes since it is the parent component of the `<Switch/>`. Thus the `useEffect(() => {}, []);` does not get fired unless the page is reloaded and the `<App/>` mounts due to the reload.

Since you have already wrapped this component within a `<Router/>`, you have access to `useLocation()` which can be used to fire the `fetchUser` function whenever the location is changed.

In addition to the below answer, you can force your site to reload when the route changes by adding `forceRefresh` to your `<Router/>`. Ex: `<Router forceRefresh ></Router>`. [Here is another answer relating to `forceRefresh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67855493/10538100) and a [documentation link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool).

#### In your case adding the following to the useEffect and imports should be sufficient:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  const isAuth = isLoggedIn();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Use the current browser location from router
  const location = useLocation();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  // Execute your `fetchUser` whenever the route changes
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchUser());
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuth) {
      return;
    }
    if (isInitial) {
      isInitial = false;
      return;
    }
      if (cart.changed) {
        dispatch(sendCartData(cart));
      }
  }, [cart]);

  return (...);
}
```

#### Here is a CodeSandbox demonstration

[image: Edit Forked React Router Demo]